# MySQL: Backup strategy - Master or Slave?

Tags: mysql, backup, master-slave

We have a set up of MySQL (version 5.1) with Master-Slave setup. 
We need to propose a backup strategy and we are going to use `mysqldump`.

We intend to use `flushlogs`, `master-date=2` and `single-transaction` options.

I just want to know from which node its better to run the backup from, Master or Slave?

Answer (score 4):

You should be running your backups on the Slave so that the Master is not interrupted in any way and the Master can stay in Production mode.

Here is a script to backup mysql data on the Slave and keep only the last 7 backups

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
BACKUP_HOME=/some/path/to/your/backups
BACKUP_TIME=`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
BACKUP_FILE=${BACKUP_HOME}/MySQLData_${BACKUP_TIME}.sql
BACKUP_GZIP=${BACKUP_FILE}.gz

MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--single--transaction --routines --triggers"
#
# Stop Replication
# Dump the Data
# Resume Replication
#
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"STOP SLAVE"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} -A | gzip > ${BACKUP_GZIP}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"START SLAVE"

#
# Rotate Out Old Backups based on BACKUPS_TO_KEEP
#
cd ${BACKUP_HOME}
FILES_TO_DELETE=/tmp/BackupFilesToDelete.txt
BACKUPS_TO_KEEP=7
BACKUPS_ON_HAND=`ls MySQLData_*.gz | wc -l`
if [ ${BACKUPS_ON_HAND} -gt ${BACKUPS_TO_KEEP} ]
then
    (( DIFF = BACKUPS_ON_HAND - BACKUPS_TO_KEEP ))
    ls -l MySQLData_*.gz | head -${DIFF} > ${FILES_TO_DELETE}
    for FIL in `cat ${FILES_TO_DELETE}` ; do rm -f ${FIL} ; done
fi
```

You cannot use `--master-data=2` because the backup is from the Slave and not the Master. If you upgrade MySQL 5.5, you could use [`--dump-slave`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-slave) in the `MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS` to capture the Master's binary log and position from the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`. You will find the output of `--dump-slave` on line 23 of the dump.

If you wish to remain with MySQL 5.1 and you want to record the coordinates from the Master, use this

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
BACKUP_HOME=/some/path/to/your/backups
BACKUP_TIME=`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
BACKUP_COOR=${BACKUP_HOME}/MySQLCoor_${BACKUP_TIME}.txt
BACKUP_FILE=${BACKUP_HOME}/MySQLData_${BACKUP_TIME}.sql
BACKUP_GZIP=${BACKUP_FILE}.gz

MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--single--transaction --routines --triggers"
#
# Stop Replication
# Dump the Data
# Capture Master Coordinates
# Resume Replication
#
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"STOP SLAVE"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} -A | gzip > ${BACKUP_GZIP}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -Ae"SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" > /tmp/SSS.txt
grep "Relay_Master_Log_File:" /tmp/SSS.txt  > ${BACKUP_COOR}
grep "Exec_Master_Log_Pos:"   /tmp/SSS.txt >> ${BACKUP_COOR}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"START SLAVE"
#
# Rotate Out Old Backups based on BACKUPS_TO_KEEP
#
cd ${BACKUP_HOME}
FILES_TO_DELETE=/tmp/BackupFilesToDelete.txt
BACKUPS_TO_KEEP=7
BACKUPS_ON_HAND=`ls MySQLData_*.gz | wc -l`
if [ ${BACKUPS_ON_HAND} -gt ${BACKUPS_TO_KEEP} ]
then
    (( DIFF = BACKUPS_ON_HAND - BACKUPS_TO_KEEP ))
    ls -l MySQLData_*.gz | head -${DIFF} > ${FILES_TO_DELETE}
    for FIL in `cat ${FILES_TO_DELETE}` ; do rm -f ${FIL} ; done
fi
```

If you want to autorotate binary logs on the Master, just configure this on the Master

```
[mysqld]
expire-logs-days=7
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question, and thanks for your backup script.

Comment: Ok, but you should add some code at the front that verifies the slave is actually in sync before you back it up.
Some people set up the slave(s) to be the server(s) you select from and only send updates to the master.  If that's your case there is no need to worry about the master unless you need 24x7 update capability.
I answered your question as well, just from a different angle.

Comment: Probably, "SHOW SLAVE" portion of script for 5.1 above should be 'mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AE -e "SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" > /tmp/SSS.txt', right?

Comment: @FumiskyWells Thank you. I just changed it to `-Ae`.

Answer (score 0):

Following is how I tackled this problem many moons ago:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
date=`date +%y%m%d`
mysql -u root db_name -e "flush tables with read lock;"
mysqldump -u root -pYrPass --add-drop-table --add-locks natl_inv > /path/to/backup/db_name$date
mysql -u root -e "reset master;"
mysql -u root db_name -e "unlock tables;"
mysql -u root –pYrPass db_name < /path/to/backup/db_name$date
mysql -u root -e "flush logs;"
```

On the slave(s): use show slave status command to verify you are in sync with the master. If you want to resync to the master, run:

```
slave stop;
reset slave;
slave start;
```

You may need to stop mysql, delete the slave bin log files then restart and run the above (this was important for us because we had a rogue app upsetting mysql configurations on the slaves).

This strategy served our purposes extremely well.  Be sure and test out to make sure it fits your needs.

Comment: How does this answer the master vs slave question ?

Comment: It runs on the master. I thought the "reset master" command made it implicit.

Comment: I know you're recommending to do the backup from the backup. The question was : why ?

Comment: This was the way we handled resetting the log files making it a quicker reliable process for the slave(s) to resync. Also slaves can be added at any time and they will get the full schema as part of their initial sync.
If you have an extremely large database you won't want to do it that way. You could just make sure the slave is in sync and reset the master. If you need to add a slave or restore the db you would use the backup first then let it sync.  It's important to reset the master so the sync logs are useful as is.

Comment: IOW just skip the second to last step if you prefer.